# Adding python3 to path using a UBUNTU 22.04 AWS EC2 instance

Tags: python, docker, amazon-ec2, path, ubuntu-22.04

I am currently following a docker tutorial and am using a VM to follow along.  Essentially the tutorial is about creating docker images from existing containers.  The task involves setting the container to use python as the executable.

```
docker commit --change='CMD ["python", "-c", "import this"]' 07a3f5a8b944 ubuntu_python
```

Whilst I am actually using python3 the issue repeats regardless of which version of python I state in the CMD.

I then attempt to run an image based on the container using

```
docker run ubuntu_python
```

but I will get this error

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "python": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
```

Looks like I need to add python to the path of the VM and google searching is not yielding anything useful.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated

thanks

Comment: Are u sure python is accessible in the docker container? for me it looks like it's not; also please add a link to the tutorial

Comment: yup, you were right  - I had not used the container where I had python3 installed.  I reinstalled python3 on the bash exec container and then created the new python exec container.  All works fine now.